# Importing json2csv module in Angular 4

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use this library in my application to convert JSON data to CSV file format. I installed the lib into my project as it mentions  https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv
`npm install json2csv --save`.
I also see the module in my node_module folder. Then in my component class i am calling it like so
 `import { json2csv } from 'json2csv';`
But then I get this error

> [ts] Module '"c:/dev/angularworkspace/tntzweb/node_modules/json2csv/index"' has no exported member 'json2csv'.

Can someone please help me!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the import to:

```
import * as json2csv  from 'json2csv';
```

Then implement as:

```
  let fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];
  let result = json2csv({ data:[{ field1: 'a', field2: 'b', field3: 'c' }], fields: fields });
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: cheers it worked but  why is it not working using the import with curly barackets. Can you please explain??

Comment: Short answer, it has to do with how the module is compiled for NPM.  Modules that are specifically compiled for Typescript/Angular will export members in a way that make them consumable using the curly bracket syntax.  Otherwise you may need to alias them using the "import * as" syntax.

Comment: Thanks, hope this will not create issue when building the app for production using webpack and AOT

Comment: I have the same issue with this var fs = require('fs'); which it uses to write to a file. Can you please guide me. I tried something like this  
`import * as  fs from 'json2csv';` but then it complains on this code
'fs.writeFile('file.csv', result, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file saved');
  });'

Comment: Import it as 'fs' instead of 'json2csv'. `import * as fs from 'fs';` this will be in addition to the json2csv import.

Comment: I tried that but it complains about the writeFile. It seems this library is not meant for Angular 2 application

Answer (score 6):

The other answers are now outdated. For json2csv version 5, first:

```
npm install --save json2csv @types/json2csv
```

Then at the top of your Angular component/service/etc:

```
import { parse } from 'json2csv';
```

Then to generate the csv in your method:

```
const csv = parse(json);
```

There are, of course, all kinds of options you can pass to `parse()` and json2csv exposes other classes and functions you can import and use as well. There are useful examples in the [tests from @types/json2csv](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/json2csv/json2csv-tests.ts).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete CSV download implementation:

```html
<a [download]="csvFileName" [href]="getCSVDownloadLink()">CSV export</a>
```

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import * as json2csv from 'json2csv';

@Component({
  selector: 'csv-download',
  templateUrl: './csv-download.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./csv-download.component.scss']
})
export class CsvDownloadComponent {

  public csvFileName = `test.csv`;

  private SOME_DATA: any[] = [{id: 1, name: 'Peter'}, {id: 2, name: 'Sarah'}];

  constructor(
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
  ) { }

  getCSVDownloadLink() {

    return this.generateCSVDownloadLink({
      filename: this.csvFileName,
      data: this.SOME_DATA,
      columns: [
        'id',
        'name',
      ],
    });
  }
  // you can move this method to a service
  public generateCSVDownloadLink(options: { filename: string, data: any[], columns: string[] }): SafeUrl {
    const fields = options.columns;
    const opts = { fields, output: options.filename };
    const csv = json2csv.parse(options.data, opts);

    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:text/csv,' + encodeURIComponent(csv));
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the angular 2 version of the library. The link to the same is: https://github.com/aqeel-legalinc/angular2-json2csv